# How can I build a python datastructure by reading it from a file

Tags: python, serialization

I would like to build a list or a list of list by reading it from a text file.

For example, I have a file 'mylist.txt' saying

```
mylist = [
1,
2,
3,
4]

myotherlist = [
 [1, 3, 4, 5],
 [3, 5, 3, 6]
]
```

I would like to read that text file and then use that in my python script.

Is that possible?
I just use the above example in python syntax.
My goal is to avoid writing parsing logic myself. And XML seems to be too complicated for my purpose.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the file have to be human editable and/or human readable?

Comment: Yes. It needs to be human editable and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a list of lists, then you should just define it "straight up" in your mylists.txt file.

e.g.

```
MYLISTS = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4],
    ...
]
```

And rename mylists.txt to mylists.py.

Then, with another Python script in the same directory, you can just do

```
import mylists
for sublist in mylists.MYLIST:
    for elem in sublist:
        ....
```

This requires no parsing code on your part, and the Python "data" file is very easy to hand-edit, too.

Comment: In the case of options files, this often proves to be a good approach.

Answer (score 4):

If I had the following data file (data.txt):-

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Then this code would read it into a list.

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('data.txt') as fsock:
   mylist = literal_eval( fsock.read() )
```

This will also work for other datatypes e.g. dictionaries. See [literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) docs for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something in the form of `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, in which case you can use `ast`:

```
In [1]: import ast

In [2]: with open('lists.txt', 'rb') as f:
   ...:     lists = f.readlines()
   ...:     
   ...:     

In [3]: list_container = [ast.literal_eval(line.strip()) for line in lists]

In [4]: list_container
Out[4]: [[1, 2, 3], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

In this case, `lists.txt` looked like this:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

However if your file looks exactly like you state above, you can use `exec`, although things like `exec` and `eval` should always be used with caution:

```
In [2]: with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
   ...:     contents = f.read()
   ...:     
   ...:     

In [3]: exec(contents)

In [4]: mylist
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [5]: myotherlist
Out[5]: [[1, 3, 4, 5], [3, 5, 3, 6]]

In [6]: print contents
mylist = [
1,
2,
3,
4]

myotherlist = [
 [1, 3, 4, 5],
 [3, 5, 3, 6]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you seemed to imply storing the list to a file as text then reading it back, Strawberry's `ast` example is probably best.  But in case you're not familiar with it, I'll also throw out the [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) method, which is a binary serialization.  It will produce smaller files and faster read/write times, at the cost of human readability and portability outside of Python.

To write:

```
import pickle # or cPickle

myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(myList, f)
```

To read:

```
import pickle

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    myList = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: my file contains multiple data structures. So how can I use 'pickle'?

Comment: You can either make multiple pickles, or you can bundle all your data structures together in some sort of structure like a tuple, list, dict, or object, depending on what's appropriate to your application.